# Laravel 5 Validation unique(database) just for same foreign key

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible to write a validation rule to check uniqueness on a field for just a specific foreign key.

[image]

So I would like to check if an Artikel(article) is unique for a Kunde(Customer).

The customer ist linked over the foreign key kunden_id.

Here is the migration file:

```
Schema::create('artikel', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        //Fremdschlüssel
        $table->integer('kunden_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('kunden_id')->references('id')->on('kunden');
        $table->string('bezeichnung');

        $table->timestamps();
    });;
```

And the Model file:

```
class Artikel extends Model {
protected $table = "artikel";

public function kunde(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Kunde');        
}

public function listPaletten(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Palette');
}
}
```

Comment: But how is the `customer` linked to the `article` table?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [unique](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-unique) validation rule for this.

```
[
    "Artikel_id" => "unique:Artikel,id,NULL,id,kunden_id," . $kunde->id
]
```

This will make sure that no row exists in the `Artikel` table with this `artikel_id` and `kunde_id`.

Comment: Thanks, i like to check if there is Artikel with the same bezeichnung and the same kunden_id

Answer (score 1):

It is **not possible** for PHP or any other language to accurately verify any kind of uniqueness in a database by selecting data first and then comparing it within the user code.

Only the database is able to tell you if something is unique.

Here is why:

By the time you query something and retrieve a result, a small amount of time will pass (for us humans it's small, but for computers it's like eons). Within that time a record can come in but you can't take the new record into account - this is due to concurrent access. Therefore, there exists the possibility of introducing new records while you're checking old records. Due to this possibility, it's by definition impossible to **accurately** determine uniqueness.

Uniqueness in databases is handled by placing unique keys upon appropriate columns and inserting data. If a clash occurs, the database denies the insert and you are certain the specified combination of information exists.

That is the only way to ensure uniqueness properly. Everything else is not safe and should not be relied upon.

In your case, that would mean you would have a table that links items to users and you place a `unique key` on `(kunden_id, artikel_id)`.

You have to **attempt** to insert into that table and if you get an exception saying that there's a duplicate record - the check failed, item exists.

Naturally, you can always say "well that case you are talking about will never happen for me" and you can query whether the record exists before inserting it - but do remember what I wrote if you get any errors in the future relating to duplicate entries.